# input type date doesn't seem to work in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have problem on using `input type date` as it will not properly work in chrome. I assume, it will have a clear button after selecting any date but it always show the square box on the right side of the date.

I just have this `<input type="date" />` in my html page.

I wonder if this is a normal behavior in chrome for input type date.

This is working perfectly in `firefox`

Here's my short fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4aq28u5L/

Comment: because each browser uses a different rendering engine. To overcome this issue, you need to build/use a custom date picker.

Comment: thanks @AbhishekTewari I'll probably use custom date pickers if this is normal for chrome.

Comment: yes this is by default added by webkit (engine) in crome. If that is the only thing bothering you then you can disable it by adding `input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator { display: none }` in your css stylesheet. [reference](https://trac.webkit.org/wiki/Styling%20Form%20Controls#Dateinputtype)

Comment: @srp thanks. I still need the calendar icon. But I need it to turn "x" button when we picked any date. Probably not possible in chrome unless using datepicker like in jquery ui.

Comment: @junm thisi is a recent change on Chrome. A week ago Chrome showed the cross to remove the content of the field. Now all users have lost that function and it seems I'll have to code it myself.

Comment: This recent change in Chrome has triggered the following issue : https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1087501